# Empty dataframe while scraping Indeed jobs

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium

I'm scraping Indeed jobs. However, the code keeps returning empty data frames. I can't figure out why. What's wrong in this code?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
HEADERS = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}



def get_current_url(url, job_title, location):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@Id="text-input-what"]').send_keys(job_title)
    driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@Id="text-input-where"]').send_keys(location)
    driver.find_element("xpath",'/html/body/div').click()
    try:
        driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="jobsearch"]/button').click()
    except:
        driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="whatWhereFormId"]/div[3]/button').click()
    
    current_url = driver.current_url
    return current_url

current_url = get_current_url('https://pk.indeed.com/','Python Developer','Karachi')



def get_jobs(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    job_list = []
    for post in content.select('.job_seen_beacon'):
        try:
            data = {
                "job_title":post.select('.jobTitle')[0].get_text().strip(),
                "company":post.select('.companyName')[0].get_text().strip(),
                "rating":post.select('.ratingNumber')[0].get_text().strip(),
                "location":post.select('.companyLocation')[0].get_text().strip(),
                "date":post.select('.date')[0].get_text().strip(),
                "job_desc":post.select('.job-snippet')[0].get_text().strip()    
            }
            except IndexError:
                continue
            job_list.append(data)
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(job_list)
    return dataframe

df = get_jobs(current_url)
print(df)
```

This is what I get in a console:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

tried to print the content and im getting something in return. the problem starts with the for loop because i tried printing the job_list without creating the data frame and i was getting an empty list so for sure the problem lies there. Plus im getting some "Can't create base directory" error as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Just a moment...</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"/>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body class="no-js">
<div class="main-wrapper" role="main">
<div class="main-content">
<h1 class="zone-name-title h1">
<img class="heading-favicon" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.parentNode.removeChild(this)" 
src="/favicon.ico"/>
            pk.indeed.com
        </h1>
<h2 class="h2" id="challenge-running">
            Checking if the site connection is secure
        </h2>
<noscript>
<div id="challenge-error-title">
<div class="h2">
<span class="icon-wrapper">
<div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>
</span>
<span id="challenge-error-text">
                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
                    </span>
</div>
</div>
</noscript>
<div id="trk_jschal_js" style="display:none;background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=758e9ba19fbac976')"></div>
<div class="core-msg spacer" id="challenge-body-text">
            pk.indeed.com needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.
        </div>
<form action="/jobs?q=Python+Developer&amp;l=Karachi&amp;from=searchOnHP&amp;vjk=6a13d1fe5a63b10e&amp;__cf_chl_f_tk=AjM4pe1DKjj23uYvh.CwSzxmrWTsDky6okLX9aVlHQk-1665564836-0-gaNycGzNB6U" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="challenge-form" method="POST">
<input name="md" type="hidden" value="DchQXGpp5HTFGMhiJoiJJ6YtHlPDGZADvN24DouRKTY-1665564836-0-ATlo029TZU0MGGL7f8GtlndxnrD9BzM4dw68FZqb-lvA-MKFN8wppTUb0LydQdQ5wLfi4DgqvKPISwnc3VcHX-Ir0MwQ315epvH71lo0OcKzZGdzfD0xza_t7oqFYps2W8d3vDtlj-wpTSKoILQxLEs2LP-gcr856M5xWsgkxwCtJnuwRgzCQKqA1ElUwHYH0axCCMHHJziLcMb7uUdjIJlX3slyjFvNwbYsr_crz18288bcqCs9Xb3rp6PESDYZ6QmuSOePAmkYs6x3vudUGCasqk3hpuLNbnSvse7UIs5Fk5iVYRAZ1ELP3EZkk6e_xiXy7xuOHRpMq23cFEivAMIvjSFI0ZQcB5b0BtKk3YyfcK2Uz2l0Zrx_BEJ8zgnjxeafeaLl2fjknQ5J4kVx7Utwf31eW2J5qNBNl1EvReZTPhfzQkIf0CxB0vZX8KgEycHOKD-an-w1-q817gjvUs5I6mPwa-qjmAL8HcChgjsgYsvE5G54ovhCtkow6rlgZS2v2QHKO5T1Z2JmJV-LyT707GxDsiBDbZyP6whd_PQAlK8t5zveCEfDXCv9HwpZJ2OP_PO52oa27-ueZ-W-jVg0D2TUYzRc-NtLrq6WgCj2cOaiVLl0abbWETF0Ugd7517mEuSWNcBScQSHy7pR_73Ys0ycjEUqDFSfGVE1K25WIPgpUez8EJ1rWDJ3SHu1r3Qj5Y3_A0hGu-laGDEQ1GoTynrWyWmxuBQmITdjYxskiXYt6ttjy9gLeOsoE2eRA7lT50bmtKgkWPSqRXPP6lECh6sfYO1-SW3Tx5g8wX9GeVcTe0gtOl5faMRUUJWCng"/>
<input name="r" type="hidden" value="0u30edMo7GSexOp3VhHVsNaza.px_mn_k2kPbYT6CZU-1665564836-0-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"/>     
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    (function(){
        window._cf_chl_opt={
            cvId: '2',
            cType: 'managed',
            cNounce: '48599',
            cRay: '758e9ba19fbac976',
            cHash: 'e7b05051acba22d',
            cUPMDTk: "\/jobs?q=Python+Developer&l=Karachi&from=searchOnHP&vjk=6a13d1fe5a63b10e&__cf_chl_tk=AjM4pe1DKjj23uYvh.CwSzxmrWTsDky6okLX9aVlHQk-1665564836-0-gaNycGzNB6U",     
            cFPWv: 'g',
            cTTimeMs: '1000',
            cTplV: 4,
            cTplB: 'cf',
            cRq: {
                ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly9way5pbmRlZWQuY29tL2pvYnM/cT1QeXRob24rRGV2ZWxvcGVyJmw9S2FyYWNoaSZmcm9tPXNlYXJjaE9uSFAmdmprPTZhMTNkMWZlNWE2M2IxMGU=',
                ra: 'TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzEwNS4wLjAuMCBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2',
                rm: 'R0VU',
                d: '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',
                t: 'MTY2NTU2NDgzNi4xMDAwMDA=',
                m: 'MuCSZkgbqmIfpGAHyzllW4MGjQ8djJCYGRl2DMVMJig=',
                i1: 'zkRIN5wRaz1CyFXOEO/WzQ==',
                i2: 'b+J2oJVLus769/IAEgyxSw==',
                zh: '2kfjrLYfAVNem19Lin3oP+VKo7ladb55se1eVtiLLnQ=',
                uh: 'hxTM763E8imxylwP68hH4R/wc4ym4Rsx7GMmWlye0AQ=',
                hh: 'g3qrs8tpQ68vLOIE7n815gZowhnVDHQi1HhKf4JuT+k=',
            }
        };
        var trkjs = document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute('src', '/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/js/transparent.gif?ray=758e9ba19fbac976');
        trkjs.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo = document.createElement('script');
        cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/managed/v1?ray=758e9ba19fbac976';
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, -window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
        if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
            history.replaceState(null, null, "\/jobs?q=Python+Developer&l=Karachi&from=searchOnHP&vjk=6a13d1fe5a63b10e&__cf_chl_rt_tk=AjM4pe1DKjj23uYvh.CwSzxmrWTsDky6okLX9aVlHQk-1665564836-0-gaNycGzNB6U" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);
            cpo.onload = function() {
                history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
</script>
<div class="footer" role="contentinfo">
<div class="footer-inner">
<div class="clearfix diagnostic-wrapper">
<div class="ray-id">Ray ID: <code>758e9ba19fbac976</code></div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">Performance &amp; security by <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com?utm_source=challenge&amp;utm_campaign=m" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Debug by printing and analysing values of `response` and `content`. May be there is no data in response or there is data; but the parsing is not filtering any.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, content is working

Comment: Pls post the `content` value.

Comment: posted. Im also getting Can't create base directory error from google chrome